# custom log entry shopware 6.4

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I have a shopware 6.4 application and I need to create custom event log entries.
creating, updating and deleting products should leave entries in event log with information about who, what and when.
I have searched through documentation but cannot find any solutions.

I have tried creating new Event

```php
use Symfony\Contracts\EventDispatcher\Event;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Event\GenericEvent;

class ProductUpdatedEvent extends Event implements GenericEvent
{
    public const EVENT_NAME = 'product.updated';
    
    public function __construct(
        protected readonly string $product,
        protected readonly string $user,
        protected readonly \DateTimeImmutable $date,
    ) {
    }

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return self::EVENT_NAME;
    }

    /**
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function getLogData(): array
    {
        return [
            'product' => $this->product,
            'user' => $this->user,
            'date' => \DateTime::createFromImmutable($this->date),
        ];
    }
}
```

and then dispatching it in subscriber

```php
public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
{
    return [
        ProductEvents::PRODUCT_WRITTEN_EVENT => 'onProductWritten',
    ];
}

public function onProductWritten(EntityWrittenEvent $entityWrittenEvent): void
{
    foreach ($entityWrittenEvent->getWriteResults() as $writeResult) {
        $event = new ProductUpdatedEvent('test', 'test', $writeResult->getPayload()['updatedAt']);
        $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch($event);
    }
}
```

but with no errors or logs being added to event log

Answer (score 1):

Do you plan on logging every update of products? The event logs are stored in the database. That adds one insert statement to every update of a product, which could be a very frequent event, depending on the administrative activity. You should also be careful not to drown important error message with purely informative logs. If you plan on releasing your plugin in the community store, writing log entries into the existing table may become an issue in the review.

The `log_entry` entity, as every other entity, has a repository `log_entry.repository` you could use to persist new entries. Shopware already [logs business event errors](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/deb5a6ec02d41617a316b2c12f55d2d7de69660f/src/Core/Framework/Log/Monolog/DoctrineSQLHandler.php#L33), but due to the possibly high frequency of these occurring, uses the lower level `Doctrine\DBAL\Connection` to persist the records. This is to minimize the performance impact of writing logs additionally to the database. So I would advise you to do so as well, if you must use the existing event logs.

```xml
<service id="MyPlugin\Subscriber\MySubscriber">
    <argument type="service" id="Doctrine\DBAL\Connection"/>
    <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber"/>
</service>
```

```php
public function __construct(Connection $connection)
{
    $this->connection = $connection;
}

public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
{
    return [
        ProductEvents::PRODUCT_WRITTEN_EVENT => 'onProductWritten',
    ];
}

public function onProductWritten(EntityWrittenEvent $entityWrittenEvent): void
{
    $queue = new MultiInsertQueryQueue($this->connection, 50, true);

    foreach ($entityWrittenEvent->getWriteResults() as $writeResult) {
        // ...

        $record = [
            'id' => Uuid::randomBytes(),
            'message' => '...',
            'level' => 1,
            'channel' => '...',
            'context' => json_encode([]),
            'extra' => json_encode([]),
            'updated_at' => null,
            'created_at' => (new \DateTime())->format(Defaults::STORAGE_DATE_TIME_FORMAT),
        ];

        $queue->addInsert('log_entry', $record);
    }

    $queue->execute();
}
```